# Is there any way to remote query tickets from trac

Tags: xml-rpc, trac

I have a trac server running at `http://127.0.0.1:8001/project/`
then i want to query the tickets by script rather than from web UI. So i searched in the internet and get the plugin `tracxmlrpc`, i installed it in my trac server and then i try to use a script to query tickets. Code as below:

```
import xmlrpclib
server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://user:111@127.0.0.1:8001/project/login/xmlrpc')
tickets = server.ticket.query('max=0')
```

But this code can not work, who can tell me how to make it work or is there any other ways to implement the remote query function.

Comment: I believe that the trackxmlrpc plugin is the best way to query your Trac install from remote.  Could you give us some more details on why the above code does not work?  Does your code return an error or just no tickets?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it can work. Much like you expected it too. Here is my verification with key configuration details:

1. An empty test project hosted at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/trac/`
2. Project configured to use Basic authentication which is the only thing supported by the Python `xmlrpclib`.
3. A user `'foo'` with password `'bar'` that have both `XML_RPC` permission (to allow calls through the API), and `TICKET_VIEW` permissions to be allowed to view tickets.
4. I created 2 tickets, `#1` is closed while `#2` is still open.

Interactive code:

```py
>>> import xmlrpclib
>>> server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://foo:bar@127.0.0.1:8000/trac/login/rpc')
>>> server.ticket.query('max=0')
[1, 2]
>>> server.ticket.query('max=0&status!=closed')
[2]
>>> server.ticket.get(2)
[2,
 <DateTime '20130104T11:48:08' at 10392c2d8>,
 <DateTime '20130104T11:48:08' at 10392c320>,
 {'_ts': '1357300088007920',
  'cc': '',
  'changetime': <DateTime '20130104T11:48:08' at 10392c368>,
  'component': 'component1',
  'description': '',
  'keywords': '',
  'milestone': 'milestone1',
  'owner': '',
  'priority': 'major',
  'reporter': 'admin',
  'resolution': '',
  'status': 'new',
  'summary': 'stackoverflow test',
  'time': <DateTime '20130104T11:48:08' at 10392c3b0>,
  'type': 'defect',
  'version': ''}]
```

This is usually always authentication or permission related, so to verify that the RPC plugin and query works you can temporarily assign `XML_RPC` and `TICKET_VIEW` permissions to user `anonymous`, and use this server proxy instead (removing `foo:bar@` and `/login` from the URL):

```py
server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://127.0.0.1:8000/trac/rpc')
```

Comment: Another way to test for authentication problems is using your browser.  If you try to access the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8001/project/login/xmlrpc`, you should be prompted for credentials and then taken to a page explaining how to use the RPC interface.  If you don't get the password prompt, then your URL is incorrect.  If you get a error logging in, doublecheck your credentials and account permissions.

Comment: No, testing authentication through a browser won't be the same. A browser has better authentication support than `xmlrpclib`. If the site has Digest authentication configured the browser will happily play along, while `xmlrpclib` will fail as it has no Digest auth support. See my answer on [this ticket](http://trac-hacks.org/ticket/9198).

Comment: The point of using the browser was merely to verify that you are using the correct URL, that your username and password are correct, and that your account has the correct permissions (things that are common mistakes in my experiences).  If one of these is indeed the problem, it's typically easier to debug and test via the browser than via script.

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug, but i've written a PHP library to interact with the Trac Bugtracker API via remote procedure calls.

https://github.com/jakoch/PHPTracRPC

Requirements

- PHP 5.3.0 or higher
- with PHP Extensions "JSON" and "cURL"
- Trac with the XmlRpcPlugin

Basic Usage Example

```
include 'TracRPC.php';

$credentials = array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password'); 

$trac = new TracRPC('http://trac.example.com/login/jsonrpc', $credentials);

$result = $trac->getTicket('32');
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Will have to check it out.